# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am getting the error described in the title in the "Line 29:21", does anyone know what is causing this error?

[image: Code]

Comment: return that component from the map

Comment: Please post text, not images of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the `<div>` from your `map()` call. Since the div you create in the map isn't returned by the map or assigned to anything, it effectively disappears after the map is finished. The warning you are seeing is the result of this `eslint` rule:

https://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/rules/no-unused-expressions#rule-details

Remember that while arrow functions [do have implicit returns](https://jaketrent.com/post/javascript-arrow-function-return-rules/), this only applies when the arrow function has a single expression as the function body.

Comment: I'd emend to say "single expression" since it isn't really limited to a single line :) And that isn't what defined whether or not there's an implicit return, it's whether or not there are curly-braces, since a single-line arrow function with curly-braces doesn't have an implicit return.

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton! I actually didn't realize that the rules worked this way, but that's what the post I linked to says as well!